# Extract data from log file and copy data to another text file using powershell

Tags: powershell, text, extract, notepad

I have data as shown below in my generated log file.

```
some data which I don't want to extract

111
222
333
444
-----------------------------Summary of Log File------------------------------------
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
No messages were found
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From the above log file I would like to extract the data from

```
-----------------------------Summary of Log File------------------------------------
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
No messages were found
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I need to copy this entire log to another text file.

This is what I'm trying

```
$log = get-content D:\Log\generatedlog.log
foreach ($line in $log) { 
    if ($line -like "*Summary of Log File*") {
$line | out-file -FilePath "D:\Log\extractedlog.txt"  -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [**#15136** Add `-From` and `-To` parameters to `Select-String`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15136): `get-content D:\Log\generatedlog.log | SelectString -From '(?=-----------------------------Summary of Log File------------------------------------)' -To '(?=------------------------------------------------------------------------------------)' |Set-Content D:\Log\extractedlog.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Try the much faster switch:

```
$inputFile  = 'D:\Log\generatedlog.log'
$outputFile = 'D:\Log\extractedlog.txt'
$copyLine   = $false
$content = switch -Regex -File $inputFile {
    '^-+Summary of Log File-+' { $copyLine = $true; $_ }
    default { if ($copyLine) { $_ }}
}
$content | Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Force  # Force to override a possible read-only attribute
```

Comment: @Theo- First thanks for your reply..Nothing is written in extractlog..Is there something I need to do ?

Comment: @coder I have updated my answer (faster because of less disk-write actions and I added the `-Force` switch to override a possible ReadOnly of the output file

Comment: @coder Using your example, this works. If nothing gets written, is your example accurate? Does the line `-----------------------------Summary of Log File------------------------------------` indeed start at the very beginning or are there surrounding spaces maybe?